# Make apache2 parse .shtml files

Tags: apache-http-server

I have just a plain-ol'-vanilla install of apache2 on ubuntu. How can I make it parse .shtml files? I've done

```
sudo a2denmod include
```

and edited /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default so it says

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Options +Includes
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
</Directory>
```

and of course

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but still when I go to a .shtml page I get

```
#include 'app_id' #include '/engine/include/fb_jssdk.include' #include '/engine/include/core.include'
```